# Allowing Android app to modify files of other apps

Tags: android

The android SDK forbids an app from modifying files of another app. However, an app like App Cache Cleaner is able to without requiring root access.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

By exploiting security holes in Android, ones that I have reported and have been ignored to date by Google.